# How does the Hex data of a .wav file reads?

Tags: matlab, audio, hex, wav

I was trying to read a .wav file with java and apparently the problem is that I don't understand how the Hex figures are supposed to be read.
Here are the first lines of *DATA* from a .wav (32 Bits per sample, 2 Channels) on a Hex editor :

```
64 61 74 61 00 1A 01 00 data.....
1D F6 FB 3D 84 DF FB 3D öû=„ßû=
4B 03 03 3E 4B 03 03 3E K..>K..>
D5 F8 08 3E D5 F8 08 3E Õø.>Õø.>
C6 48 0F 3E C6 48 0F 3E ÆH.>ÆH.>
```

So here is what I thought : the first value from the first channel should be read : 3D FB F6 1D, which would mean 1039922717

And so I take that number and substract 2^31 and I get -1107560931 and that would be the first value. But then I compare this to the value I get from MATLAB audioread and I get 264200656 as first value. Why ?

Comment: its always easier if you first write some code to create the file then you know what went in when battling how to read it back ... also I suggest you deal with a mono file for starters ... be clear whether your data is signed or unsigned ... WAV can also be float make sure you have ints not floats ... the header is just a nice to have no need to deal with it initially ... write some code to write a few bytes to a file then write more code to read it back ... that approach reduces the unknowns

Comment: critical aspect of combining multiple bytes is notion of endianness ... do some research on how each byte is shifted to make room for next byte of a multi byte bit depth file ... bit depth of 8 fits in a single byte so is easiest to read and write ... get your code working on a bit depth of 8 bits first then worry about 16 bits or 32 ... when working with multi byte audio as with 4 bytes of 32 bit audio, the value of a byte is shifted